# Get TextBox name from WPF application with MVVM model in helper class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

So I am trying to build a MVVM application with WPF and i am stuck with this problem: 
In the view class, I have a list of textBoxes that I want to acces in order to validate the inputs. 
So I managed to do this by writing in the view class, and it works:

```
var list = mainGrid.Children.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();
        var dictOfTb = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            dictOfTb.Add(item.Name, item.Text);
        }
```

But the problem is that I am trying to respect the MVVM pattern and I should to this in a helper class, lets call it ModelsPageHelper, and access it from the View, because here what I am trying to do is to only get data from the UI and pass it to the viewModel to get a result, and then to display it.
So in this class I wrote a method,`GetValuesFromTextBoxes(List<TextBox> textBoxes)` and I am writing the same code, but now I get a message saying that TextBox does not contain a definition for Name.

So the question is, how can I do the same thing in the helper class to acces the names of those textBoxes?

Comment: "get data from the UI and pass it to the viewModel " - this part is done via Bindings, not helper classes

Comment: U should bind your text strings as collection and manage them in ViewModel

Comment: Maybe you could use IValueConverter or IErrorDatainfo perhaps in the view. It is not difficult and there are many examples on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do MVVM properly you have to stop thinking about code to validate text boxes, and think about a ViewModel that validates itself, and a view that displays the state of the ViewModel.

For example, if you have a property called `Foo` which must have the value `Bar`, the code would look like this:

```
public string FooError { get; private set; }

private string foo;
public string Foo
{
    get => return foo;
    set
    {
        foo = value;
        if (foo == "Bar") FooError = "";
        else FooError = "Foo must be Bar";

        NotifyPropertyChanged();
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(FooError));
    }
 }
```

and your XAML would look something like this:

```
 <TextBox Text={Binding Foo}/>
 <TextBlock Text={Binding FooError}/>
```

Then perhaps your save button could check for errors too.

I'd strongly advise you to look into `INotifyDataErrorInfo`, which is a great way to organise your errors in a way that WPF can easily display (instead of properties like `FooError`). It might seem like a lot of work the first time you use it, but it's great once you've got lots of controls and validation rules.

Comment: The problem is that I am trying to implement WHERE operation, so, let's say, I have defined a student with fields FirstName, LastName, Age and ID, and I can't use the same validation method for this because the user may want to find students where id='a value' and age='value'. or by firstname, and lastname. And when the user inputs the values, it is routed in the web api as a string of "?column=value&column=value..." and so on, and I have to find out which textbox has a value and  which doesn't, so I can be able to send the request.

Comment: But this looks good and propper and I will try to implement it on 'Create New' operation or 'delete', where I always know which textbox should contain values and which sould not.